# multiline string findIndex()

Tags: javascript, string, find, multiline

I'm trying to find a multiline substring inside my string.

My code:

```js
data = `if (res) {
                                new PNotify({
                                    title: TAPi18n.__('success'),
                                    text: TAPi18n.__('image_uploaded'),
                                    type: 'info',
                                    styling: 'bootstrap3'
                                });
                            }
                            if (err) {
                                return new PNotify({
                                    title: TAPi18n.__('error'),
                                    text: err,
                                    type: 'error',
                                    styling: 'bootstrap3'
                                });
                            }`;

/*not found...*/
match = `new PNotify({
              title: TAPi18n.__('error'),
              text: err,
              type: 'error',
              styling: 'bootstrap3'
            })`;
console.log(data);
console.log(match);
console.log(data.indexOf(match));
```

That line `console.log(data.indexOf(match));` shows me `-1`.
What's wrong with my code? How can I do that multiline search?

Comment: `match` doesn't have the same number of spaces at the beginning of each line as the matching part of `data`.

Comment: You need to use a regular expression if you want to allow variable amount of whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the amount of spaces don't match between `match` and `data`.

You can convert `match` to a regular expression that allows variable amount of whitespace.

The first `match.replace()` is used to escape all the special regexp characters in the string, the second converts whitespace to `\s+` so it will match any amount.

```js
data = `if (res) {
                                new PNotify({
                                    title: TAPi18n.__('success'),
                                    text: TAPi18n.__('image_uploaded'),
                                    type: 'info',
                                    styling: 'bootstrap3'
                                });
                            }
                            if (err) {
                                return new PNotify({
                                    title: TAPi18n.__('error'),
                                    text: err,
                                    type: 'error',
                                    styling: 'bootstrap3'
                                });
                            }`;


match = `new PNotify({
              title: TAPi18n.__('error'),
              text: err,
              type: 'error',
              styling: 'bootstrap3'
            })`;
re = new RegExp(match.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&').replace(/\s+/g, '\\s+'));

result = data.match(re);
console.log(result && result.index);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to **normalize** your strings before comparing them

Here's a simple function to split your string by lines and removes whitespaces for every line before joining everything back together

```js
function normalizeString(str){
  return str.split('\n').map(e => e.trim()).join('')
}
```

Output:

```js
data = `if (res) {
                                new PNotify({
                                    title: TAPi18n.__('success'),
                                    text: TAPi18n.__('image_uploaded'),
                                    type: 'info',
                                    styling: 'bootstrap3'
                                });
                            }
                            if (err) {
                                return new PNotify({
                                    title: TAPi18n.__('error'),
                                    text: err,
                                    type: 'error',
                                    styling: 'bootstrap3'
                                });
                            }`;

/*not found...*/
match = `new PNotify({
              title: TAPi18n.__('error'),
              text: err,
              type: 'error',
              styling: 'bootstrap3'
            })`;

// normalize strings
var normalizedData = data.split('\n').map(e => e.trim()).join('')
var normalizedMatch = match.split('\n').map(e => e.trim()).join('')

console.log(normalizedData)
console.log(normalizedMatch)
console.log(normalizedData.indexOf(normalizedMatch));
```